# Why foo(short int *) and bar(signed short *) considered different signature by QT?

Tags: c++, qt

```
QObject::connect: Incompatible sender/receiver arguments
    Bar::bar(signed short*) --> Foo::foo(short int*)
```

Is there a way to make QT smarter on this kind of thing, or shall I use coding standard to avoid this kind of bizarre?

Edit: above error message is a runtime error message from a failed `connect()` call.

Comment: Hint: Qt is not the one deciding what your primitive data types are. C++ is.

Comment: `signed short *` in a signal/slot context ? my eyes are bleeding.

Comment: Probably because Qt's meta compiler doesn't care about actual types, but about them having the same string of characters.

Comment: @Xeo I don't think it is that simple. But yes it might be a bug in Qt's MOC that fails to realize that `signed short*` and `short int *` are the same. To be honest who would write that ... signed in 100% useless in this context, `short int` is really `short` but for thick people, and don't get me started on the usefulness of using a `short` instead of a plain int inside a QT slot... performance ? yeah right..

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I don't think so. This doesn't look like a compiler error message. There isn't even an explicit mention of type. this is Qt's Moc error message.

Comment: Reading it again, it indeed seems to be a problem with MOC.

Comment: @FélixCantournet This is actually a runtime error message from a connect() call.

Comment: @user3528438 Hum. I though the MOC would check this at (pre-)compile time.

Comment: I believe this is a compile time error. The runtime error would say something like "No SLOT found". It would not complain about the type mismatch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two syntaxes to make signal and slot connections:

Old:

```
connect(sender, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), receiver, SLOT(updateValue(int)));
```

New:

```
connect(sender, &Sender::valueChanged, receiver, &Receiver::updateValue);
```

The old syntax uses the `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros. When it comes to this syntax, Qt's meta compiler is dumb -- it relies on string parsing. If the strings don't match, you don't connect. On my system (that has a 32 bit `int`), I cannot connect a `someFunc(int)` to a `anotherFunc(int32_t)`. Worse, I cannot connect a `someFunc(int32_t)` to `anotherFunc(int32_t)` without registering the type with `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` and `qRegisterMetaType<T>()`. Fun!

You should probably always use the new syntax. It uses member function pointers and benefits from compile-time checking

Pros:

- Compile time check of the existence of the signals and slot, of the
  types, or if the Q_OBJECT is missing.
- Argument can be by typedefs or with different namespace specifier, and it works.
- **Possibility to
  automatically cast the types if there is implicit conversion (e.g.
  from QString to QVariant)**
- It is possible to connect to any member
  function of QObject, not only slots.

I believe the new syntax should solve your problem.

See [New Signal Slot Syntax](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax)

Answer (score 3):

If you want you can probably make some Qt developpers miserable by reporting this as a bug in the MOC type-checking thingy that they use to check signal/slot arguments match.

But more seriously : don't do this ! Name the same type consistently. Just use `short *`.

Anything else is just not nice to the other kids.